# why we use interface in retrofit

Tags: java, android, oop, retrofit

How retrofit make use of interface when making network request, first we define interface and pass it to create method of retrofit how does these things work together

```
BooksAPI api = adapter.create(BooksAPI.class);

    //Defining the method
    api.getBooks(new Callback<List<Book>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Book> list, Response response) {

            //Storing the data in our list
            books = list;

            //Calling a method to show the list
            showList();
        }
```

Comment: can you look at the source of method create which should give you a hint!.

Comment: It's called "annotation processing" and is a method to generate Java byte at build time. A google search should come up with decent examples and blog posts.

Comment: i add, you can think of that interface as a configuration file, it holds info (method declaration , return type and params, annotations) about each endpoint (link a method name to url, GET or POST, parameters and parameter types, return value type , ... and more). the engine uses those info to serialize parameters (if needed), execute the request and deserialize the response (if needed)

Comment: could you answer in detail

Comment: so these interface don't need body and we are not implementing any where

Comment: I think retrofit generating its implementation itself, what do you say